# Webpack not running on Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I have created a new Rails **5.1** (since I need to read from  MS SQL Server database I can't use 5.2 yet) app and I wish to use `Webpacker`.

`Node` and `Yarn` are installed and `Webpacker` has been initialized when I have created the app (I have passed `--webpack` to the `rails new` command).

I have added `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>` to my layout.
I have started the `webpack-dev-server`

```
$ ./bin/webpack-dev-server
Project is running at http://localhost:3035/
webpack output is served from /packs/
Content not from webpack is served from /app51/public/packs
404s will fallback to /index.html
Hash: 3bafe7a1096030dc6cac
Version: webpack 3.12.0
Time: 1460ms
```

However, when I go to the root my console is empty no `Hello World from Webpacker` is displayed.

Am I missing anything?

Not sure if that may be helpful, but I have noticed webpack live-reload is not working. If, for instance, I update my `app/javascript/packs/application.js` to `console.log('Hello World from Webpacker !!!!')` nothing happens on the dev-server.

Comment: I was thinking about a solution for your last's question problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57759072/get-all-values-in-a-hash-with-array-as-keys

Comment: @SebastianPalma  Thanks, since the -2, I have decided to do another way completely.

Comment: Don't worry, that always happens. Take a look to this, might help: `hash = {['a', 'b'] => [1,2,3], ['c','a'] => [4,5,6], ['b', 'd'] => [7]};
hash.each_with_object([]) do |(k, v), arr|
  k.each { |key| arr << [key] + v } if k.is_a?(Array)
end.group_by(&:first).transform_values { |value| value.flatten.select { |e| e.is_a?(Integer) } }`

Comment: @SebastianPalma Thanks for your help.